# Swift disable copy, cut, paste in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I know how to disable the standard copy, paste, cut... options in Swift when editing a `UITextField`'s / `UITextView`'s text but I don't know how to do this with a `UISearchBar`. With a text field I would subclass `UITextField` and override the `canPerformAction()` method. But when subclassing `UISearchBar` this does not work and I don't know how to address the searchBar's textField. Furthermore I would really like to know, how you could change the color of the little 'X' on the right site of the search bar's text field, which is responsible for deleting all the text in the text field.

Would be great if someone could help me with these two things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a way to disable copy paste ?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to change the clear button color is to use a custom image by calling

```
setImage(_ iconImage: UIImage?, forSearchBarIcon icon: UISearchBarIcon, state state: UIControlState)
```

on the `UISearchBar`.

As to disabling copy/paste on the `UISearchBar`'s text field, I don't think there is a way to do that. Even if you get access to the `UITextField` instance contained in it, there's no way you'd be able to change the behaviour for that particular instance.